# Unable to change NSNumber to Double and do some calculations with it

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, sum, double, nsnumber

my problem is that i have an Array that holds some double values

```
NSArray *level4results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

then i sum up all the values in that array

```
NSNumber *l4sum = [level4results valueForKeyPath:@"sum.self"];
```

The next thing i want to do is to divide by 8 the sum of the array... and this is where i am stuck. I have tried many options and ways of doing it by either way i kept on getting different error. This is what i have currently in my code

```
double l4average = ([l4sum doubleValue] / 8);
```

however this is throwing following error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI doubleValue]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance

Help in solving this problem appreciated. Thanks

Comment: did that and still getting the same sort of error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the collection operator. This line:

> `NSNumber *l4sum = [level4results valueForKeyPath:@"sum.self"];`

Should be written:

`NSNumber *l4sum = [level4results valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"];`

Answer (score 2):

The sum operator needs an `@`:

```
@"@sum.self"
```