# retrieving number from array that can be manipulated

Tags: objective-c, arrays, int

I am trying to retrieve a number that is stored in an array so that i can manipulate it at a later stage.

for example i have a sum in the array i.e. 500 and i would like to divide that number by x.

how would this be accomplished?

so far i have this and it doesn't work:

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *level4results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", level4results);//check sum value of array

int l4sum = ((int)[level4results indexOfObject:0]) / 7;
NSLog(@"%d", l4sum); //check if l4sum gets values passed
```

the output was:

```
      2013-05-19 18:50:49.648 bla.v1[6254:c07] (
        {
        sumValue = 633;
    }
)
2013-05-19 18:50:49.650 bla.v1[6254:c07] 306783378
```

Comment: You want `objectAtIndex:`, not `indexOfObject:`.

Comment: still didn't make a difference the trailing number is not what is required or what it is

Comment: Where does that code come from? Similar code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630869/unable-to-change-nsnumber-to-double-and-do-some-calculations-with-it.

Comment: the code comes from my head? and the other question was also submited by me but it releated to different problem. now i am trying to manipulate the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using [level4results objectAtIndex:0] instead of [level4results indexOfObject:0] ?

Comment: Try this: NSDictionary *dic = [level4results objectAtIndex:0]; int l4sum = [(NSNumber *)[dic valueForKey:@"sumValue"] intValue];

Comment: Yep the think in comment works perfectly :D. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

C types like "`int`" and "`float`" are not Objective-C objects and can't be directly saved in Objective-C "`NSArrays`".

But you can set and get numbers in your array via using Objective-C "`NSNumber`" objects.

And it looks like what IS in your array is a "`NSDictionary`".

E.G.:

```
NSDictionary * dictionaryFromArray = [level4results indexOfObject: 0];
if(dictionaryFromArray)
{
    NSNumber * sumNumber = [dictionaryFromArray objectForKey: @"sumValue];
    if(sumNumber)
    {
         int l4sum = [sumNumber intValue];

         l4sum = (l4sum / 7);
    }
}
```